# Python: Arguments over multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to put a generator that always returns 'True' in one line? The reason for that being is that it should be a default parameter in a function or is there a way to use these parameters having multiple lines?

This should be the default argument of a function:

```
def example_function(generator= (def gen():
                                    while True:
                                        yield True)):
                                            print("In my function")
```

The code with that indentation shows the following syntax error:

```
def example_function(generator= (def gen():
                                   ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly that's what you need:

```py
def example_function(generator=None):

   def default_generator():
       while True:
           yield True

  generator = generator or default_generator
```

There is generally no reason to put things in one line. On the other hand you could also use [`itertools.repeat(True)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to define the `default_generator`, it would save few lines of code:

```py
import itertools

def example_function(generator=None): 
    generator = generator or itertools.repeat(True)
```

In general it's a good idea to use `x=None` for default keyword arguments with default values. You can have a look at why [using an object instead of `None` can be risky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) (functions are objects too, so this applies here).

Comment: awesome, great advice!